how do i export every part of the model
when I export my model from blender to unity some of the objects parts are missing and i can't seem to fix the problem? does anyone know what the problem is?



There can be many issues, you could upload the file to get inspected. Most common is unapplied transforms (Ctrl A). Re-importing into a new Blender file is correct?


